Angular is refreshing page on code changing
On vscode any angular code changing triggers a page refresh which reset all states from my current route getting it so frustating to develop over. I'd like to change the app without reloading entire page like  vite on react
Below is my angular json:
   "architect": {
       ...
      "build": {
        ...
        "serve": {
            "options": {
                  "liveReload": true
                 },

And package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --live-reload",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },


Have you tried Angular 19's NG_HMR_TEMPLATES=1 ng serve?

Hot module reload, HMR is a feature that partially landed in v19.
It includes

Style HMR
External Template HMR with the flag NG_HMR_TEMPLATES=1

In v19.1, that feature will be extended to include inline templates & won't require the flag anymore.
There is no visibility on HMR for the component itself.

I set the flat --hmr, and angular is still reloading page on view updates is that normal? if I disable page reloads, page will (obviously) not reload but no changes will be reflected
